# #if DEBUG and debug build?

Tags: c#

The following code will print the string if debugging in Visual Studio.

```
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("...In visual studio...");
#endif
```

Will it print the string if running the compiled exe file under the direction of `...\bin\Debug` directly?

Comment: If you build and run the `debug` build target then yes, this code line will be compiled as part of your code (assuming you did not manually suppress/turned of the DEBUG flag in your project/build settings). That of course means it will be executed. However, if you compile the `release` build target then this line will not be part of the code of your program and not be executed, no matter whether you are in VS or not...

Comment: It depends not on the location of the binary, but the flags sent to the compiler when building. In the C# project properties Build tab, there is an option to define the DEBUG and TRACE constants. If DEBUG is defined, then it will be printed. By default, both TRACE and DEBUG are selected for Debug configuration, and only TRACE for the Release configuration.

Comment: "_if running in Visual Studio_" I sense some confusion here. Once compiled, the program will run the same no matter whether it is started from VS or from somewhere else. The compiled code will not magically retroactively change and behave differently just because you execute the same exe not from within VS...

Comment: And what happened when you actually ran the program?  Given that you've already written it, it's taken you *dramatically* longer to write this question than it would have taken you to double click on the executable that you'd already written.

Comment: @Servy I also wanted to know the reasoning behind. The accepted answer explained it well.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Then why ask what the result of the program is, if that's not actually what  you wanted to know?  If you want to know what the result of executing the program you've written is, run it.  If you want to know why it produces the result it does, then do your research, and if you can't figure it out after looking up the related topics, then ask *that* question.

Comment: @elgonzo Why did you write that as a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `#...` directives are processed by the **compiler**. They are **NOT** found in the final .exe file. They are **NOT** executed in runtime.

That means that in this case what matters is, what was the state of things at the moment of compiling. If you built your .exe as a DEBUG build, then the `DEBUG` constant was defined and consequently your .exe file will contain code for the `Console.WriteLine("...In visual studio...");` line. When you run this .exe file, no matter when or where or how, it will output the line to the console.

On the other hand, if you built your application as a RELEASE build, then the `DEBUG` constant will not be defined, and the compiler will not add the line to the .exe file. You will not get the .exe file to print your line, no matter what you do. If you look at the .exe file with a decompiler, you won't even find the string `"...In visual studio..."` in there. It will be as if you had never written that line in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where you run the application, what matters is how you built it. When you select debug build the compiler declares the `DEBUG` constant, when you run the `exe` the `if` branch will be executed because the constant was declared.

In Visual Studio you can see the declared constants by going `Build` tab under `Project Properties`, if you try to change build mode to `Release` while you are there, you can see that "*Define DEBUG constant*" will get unchecked automatically.